# Convertendo Arquivo DOCX para PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, microsoft-word

Estou com uma aplicação e preciso converter um arquivo `DOCX` para `PDF` sem perder a formatação.

Encontrei algumas DLL que auxiliam, mas para uso corporativo tem que comprar licença então fica complicado.

Complementando fiz mais algumas pesquisas e encontrei alguns posts que usam  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É bem fácil utilizar a biblioteca `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` para converter para PDF.
No entanto, é necessário que o MS-Word esteja instalado na máquina onde for rodar a aplicação.

Um exemplo de código em `C#` para fazer a conversão é o seguinte:

```
string arqDoc = @"C:\Desenv\DocTeste.docx";
string arqPdf = @"C:\Desenv\DocTeste.pdf";

var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(arqDoc);

wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(arqPdf, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);       

wordDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente, Muito bom.